# Trouble with Texmaker and biblatex

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, bibtex, biber

I'm using Texmaker 5.1.3.
I'm trying to compile a document using an external file called references.bib as a bibliography.

These are my attempts:
Using LaTeX or PDFLaTeX: no bibliography appears on the pdf file;
Using BibTeX: no pdf file produced

My minimal "working" example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[full]{textcomp}
\usepackage[greek,italian]{babel}
\usepackage[margin=2cm,top=1cm,headheight=16pt,headsep=0.1in,heightrounded]{geometry}
\usepackage[colorlinks,citecolor=blue,linkcolor=blue,bookmarks,bookmarksopen=false,bookmarksdepth=3,pdfstartview=FitH,pdfencoding=unicode,psdextra,]{hyperref}


\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}



\title{Cool title}
\author{The Author}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\begin{flushleft}
 
\section{Estrazione}
\subsection{Estrazione con solvente}
L'estrazione con solvente si basa sul gradiente di concentrazione presente fra biomassa e il solvente stesso. I cannabinoidi diffondono dai tricomi ghiandolari verso il solvente: questo fenomeno rappresenta da un punto di vista cinetico il passaggio che determina la velocità del processo globale. 
L'estrazione con solvente consiste nella macerazione del materiale vegetale contente i cannabinoidi in solventi polari o apolari \cite{Ramirez}. 

\end{flushleft}

\end{document}

latex test
bibtex references
latex test
```

Comment: No bibliography without cites (e.g., `\autocite`, `\cite`, `\nocite`) and without `\printbibliography`. BTW: `bibtex references` is wrong. First of all you should use `biber` and both, `bibtex` and `biber` expects the basename of the main tex file not the basename of the `bib` file. And unfortunately your example is not a [working example with bibliography](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4407/how-to-write-a-mweb-minimal-working-example-with-bibliography) and therefore not working for us.

Comment: Off-topic: Using a `flushleft` *environment* for several pages or (almost) the whole document is usually not the best idea and should be replaced by *command* `\raggedright` (or `\RaggedRight` using package `ragged2e`).

Comment: This document needs to be compiled with Biber, not BibTeX. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864 on how to configure your editor to do that for you. As cabohah mentioned, though, this particular example document has no citations and no bibliography command, so `biblatex` won't do anything useful. You need to actually cite some sources and place `\printbibliography` where you want the bibliography (of cited entries) to appear.

Comment: Solved, thanks @moewe